# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://wcfjsproxydemo/bundles/modernizr?v=Vd40cG5fYxxjdknf_y9ilK-zi7pnjL35tk9IAsOQgQc1"

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-7

After deploy my ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms site under IIS7 I got error that didn't have when run from VS2013.

The errors on browsing my site from firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - h t t p://wcfjsproxydemo/bundles/modernizr?v=Vd40cG5fYxxjdknf_y9ilK-zi7pnjL35tk9IAsOQgQc1"
modern...sOQgQc1
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - h t t p://wcfjsproxydemo/Content/css?v=f5ydPh92LWsttS1MEc8JZmFtAgT6RUaer_jy37xBkQs1"
css?v=...7xBkQs1
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - h t t p://wcfjsproxydemo/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=J4joXQqg80Lks57qbGfUAfRLic3bXKGafmR6wE4CFtc1"
MsAjax...E4CFtc1
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - h t t p://wcfjsproxydemo/bundles/WebFormsJs?v=q9E9g87bUDaS624mcBuZsBaM8xn2E5zd-f4FCdIk2cA1"
WebFor...dIk2cA1
TypeError: Sys.WebForms is undefined


...bForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ctl08', 'ctl01', [], [], [], 90, 'c...

wcfjsproxydemo (line 67)
POST http://intext.nav-links.com/util/intexteval.pl?op=eval&x=3&xop=eval&rnum=911043

200 OK
        214ms   
intext...inks=3& (line 3039)
```

I see my site without style.

What should I change here in my site?

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WCFJSproxyDemo-20130722004707;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WCFJSproxyDemo-20130722004707.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
    <controls><add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" /></controls></pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.WCFJSproxyDemoBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>   
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.DemoWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.WCFJSproxyDemoBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFJSproxyDemo.Service.IDemoWCFService">
        </endpoint>
      </service> 
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="default.aspx" />
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="TestWCFService.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

After some hours working in this issue I found a [blog](http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2012/11/fixing-404-errors-for-aspnet-mvc-apps.html) with just one think to do:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">  
  <remove name="BundleModule" />  
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />  
</modules>
```

Optimization.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Static/css/stylesheets.css")
                .Include(
                        "~/Static/stylesheets/base.css",
                        "~/Static/stylesheets/layout.css"
                )
            );



            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Static/js/script.js")

                .Include("~/Static/js/jquery.refineslide.min.js", 
                         "~/Static/js/script.js"));
```

Root.Master

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cssBundle" runat="server">
     <%= System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Static/css/stylesheets.css") %>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
.
.
.
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      <%= System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Static/js/script.js") %>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.net forms, 
Just you have to change  modules in webconfig to the below

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">  
  <remove name="BundleModule" />  
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />  
</modules>
```